# How to get linux kernel character driver FOPS?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, device-driver

@ All,

Have got a requirement to replace a character driver ioctl function pointer. Would like to tap into the ioctl implementation of a character driver and replace that function pointer with mine(so that, we could intercept all calls getting into that character device, say X).

Have checked,  include/linux/fs.h & fs/char_dev.c. Didn't find any pointers/hints for tapping in character driver IOCTL implementation.

Kernel version used : 4.9.35 (Any kernel version above 3.10 should be also fine).

Can someone point at any possible way if it exists ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Tried using the below code,

Comment: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9.35/source/fs/char_dev.c#L246

Mentioning the above code from lxr for the function,  chrdev_open() which uses a logic to build the cdev_map and get the targeted character device object. Code snippet in the above uses, kobj_lookup() and  kobj_map_init() to get the cdev_map and the cdevs. Looks like kobj_lookup and kobj_map_init() functions are not visible/exported so that it can't be used. 

Can someone help to get this going further?

Comment: every device driver implements its own "ioctl" fops-structure.
Not sure what you want to do? Learn to modify an existing driver or try override the behavior of all loaded drivers in the kernel?

Comment: @David Bern, For a requirement to tap into the Character driver, we need access/get into the fops implementation of the character driver and replace with our function in the place of the original and call the original function from ours. So that tapping is doable.  This is the requirement.

Comment: Learn to modify an existing driver or try override the behavior of all loaded drivers in the kernel?                                                                                              Can you send me more explanation on this w.r.t to the code?  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Have a look into the Linux kernel repo. It's full of examples. There is also plenty of articles written about the subject. Don't think I have any to add, except doing the googling for you